# Difference between "zweifeln", "anzweifeln" and "bezweifeln"

Tags: verb, meaning-in-context

I was looking at the verb form from the word "Zweifel" and I found 3 different words:

- zweifeln
- anzweifeln
- bezweifeln

It probably is subtle, but could someone explain me the difference between them, and where I can and can not use them in context?

Comment: the differences are subtle indeed - I'm struggling to put them in words

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are indeed very subtle differences in both meaning and usage.

Something that hasn't been mentioned here before: you can use `zweifeln` without any object at all:

> Ich zweifle.

would be possible to say and is as general as `Ich denke.` or `Ich glaube.`

Another example:

> Glaubst Du nun endlich an die Auferstehung?
>   Nein, ich zweifle immer noch.

You can also use `zweifeln` with a relative clause starting with `ob` to express having doubts about some decision or move:

> Ich zweifle, ob ich ihm glauben soll.

In all these examples you could not use `anzweifeln` or `bezweifeln` instead.

`Anzweifeln` and `bezweifeln` can both have a direct object. With `zweifeln` you would use the preposition `an` in these cases. `Bezweifeln` and `zweifeln` can be followed by a relative clause. With `zweifeln` you may insert `daran`, then.

> Niemand zweifelte [daran], dass es gelingen würde.

(example taken from the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zweifeln))

For the differences in meaning I think it's worthwhile pointing out the difference between `having doubts` and `expressing doubts`. `Anzweifeln` always implies the latter. That's why you cannot use it instead of `zweifeln` in

> Sie sah mich an, als zweifle sie an meinem Verstand.

(same source)

`zweifeln` is more often used for `having doubts` and `bezweifeln` for `expressing doubts` (in particular you can say `Ich bezweifle, dass ...` to express you are having doubts ;-)), but (often) you can use both of them for the other, too. Let's look again at

> Niemand zweifelte [daran], dass es gelingen würde.

This would rather mean `nobody having doubts` and would it leave unclear wether they talked about being sure, while

> Niemand bezweifelte, dass es gelingen würde.

would rather stress the point that nobody said he/she had doubts. (To use `anzweifeln` here you would need to transform the relative clause into an object: `das Gelingen des Vorhabens`, but that would result in a rather poor style.)

In cases where both `anzweifeln` and `bezweifeln` are a choice you would use `anzweifeln` if the doubts are rather weak or just starting to grow and `bezweifeln` if they are already profound and solid.

Answer (score 6):

These words are indeed very closely related and can be used synonymously in most cases.

All of the above express that I doubt the correctness of this statement.

> Ich zweifle an der Richtigkeit dieser Aussage.
>
> Ich zweifle die Richtigkeit dieser Aussage an.
>
> Ich bezweifle die Richtigkeit dieser Aussage.

There is no significant difference af meaning between the three that I'm aware of.

In some situations, one of them might be a bit more idiomatic than the others. The following examples might be from some newspaper article:

> Der Abgeordnete zweifelte (offen) die Führungsqualitäten des Parteichefs an.

This basically implies that the representative (openly/publicly) attacked the party head by expressing doubts about his ability to lead. You wouldn't use *bezweifeln* to express that. You could, however, also use *Zweifel* as a noun:

> Der Abgeordnete äußerte Zweifel an den Führungsqualitäten des Parteichefs.

… which has the same meaning, but might sound a bit less aggressive.

> Der Abgeordnete zweifelt an den Führungsqualitäten des Parteichefs.

… would not necessarily require that he actually said anything. This could just be an assumption on the part of a commentator, based on other statements/observations.

*Bezweifeln* is more often used in direct speech:

> Ich bezweifle (nicht), dass er das wirklich ernst meint.

In spoken language

> Ich bezweifle das.

is more common than

> Ich zweifle daran.

…, although both versions mean the same, i.e. "I doubt it/that".

Comment: Why wouldn't you use "bezweiflen" in the first "Abgeordnete" example? Would it sound weird? Or just plain incorrect?

Comment: I'm not sure - it's just not used for expecting doubt of qualities. `"Der Abgeordnete bezweifelte die Führungsqualitäten..."` would sound unusual. You could say `"Der Abgeodnete bezweifelte, dass die Führungsqualitäten [...] für diese schwierige Situation ausreichend sind."` or something like that - this makes the object the statement from the subordinate clause, not the qualities themselves, which would be fine.

Comment: Im not sure I understood what you meant...

Comment: @Dbugger IMHO you could use "bezweifeln" in the first "Abgeordnete" example as well. Depending on what had been said in the situation being described it might even be the better choice. Let's imagine the deputee said "Lieber X, ich bezweifle [or: ich glaube nicht], daß Du noch in der Lage bist, die Partei in dieser Situation zu führen." The record of this meeting should then use "bezweifeln". "Anzweifeln" would be too weak to describe this open and direct expression of doubts.

Comment: @Matthias My point was that (to my ears at least) it sounds wrong to say "Ich bezweifle deine Führungsqualitäten"

Comment: @Hulk I see. Not to my ears, though...

Comment: From the comments I am reading, I am understanding that "zweifeln" and "anzweifeln" is used to express a hesitation (for instance, `When I tried to answer the questions of the exam, I doubted`). On the other hand, "bezweifeln" seems like it is used to "put into question" something that might be taken as correct by others. (For instance: `I doubt that what he says is true`). Did I get it right?

Comment: It feels like `bezweifeln` is about **actively** doubting or bringing into doubt something, meanwhile the others occur more **passively**

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there are differences in grammar. "Anzweifeln" and "bezweifeln" can both take a direct object, while "zweifeln" connects with an object using the preposition "an" (which is likely where "anzweifeln comes from :)

> Ich zweifele an etwas.

vs.

> Ich zweifele etwas an.
>   Ich bezweifele etwas.

As far as meaning goes, I'd say that "anzweifeln" is the weakest doubting. The an-prefix gives it a bit of the notion of starting to doubt, though that's not always the intended meaning. "Zweifeln" is a bit stronger and "bezweifeln" is pretty solid doubting work.

Comment: So if the only semantic difference is the strength of the doubt, does it mean that they can be replaced in any sentence, and it would be always correct?

Comment: @Dbugger... well, as long as you do the different grammar justice the resulting sentence will be about the same thing... doubting. Whether or not the nuance/strength matters is a question of style and context I suppose. One writer might be totally against "zweifeln an" claiming that it's totally different from his "anzweifeln". But objectively,  I wouldn't know how

Comment: I think that "anzweifeln" implies that you voice your doubts, while you can "bezweifeln" silently.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... very good point

Comment: It seems a little odd to me that the verb which represents the weakest doubt (anzweifeln) also implies that you voice it. Usually, you voice your doubt when it is strong.